# How I can parse string variable like that

Tags: c#

I need to parse this string with C# but don't know how. Would you advise me on a good way to get values from this string" Arrays "

```
["root",[["t-a2hICACK35I","isYktsZwEVMQ","r-isYktsZwEVMQ",[["global_config",null,null,null,null,[null,"[\"AOvVaw0H3zstE2R8Hh96uT8kZylb\\u0026ust\\u003d1511890102832262\",null,0,null,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,null,1,1,1,1,0,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,0,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,0,0,null,null,1,null,400,null,null,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,0,0,\"NONE\",null,4,\"Related image\",7,0,\"%1$d\\u0026nbsp;\\u0026#215;\\u0026nbsp;%2$d\",0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,\"#222\",0,1,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,0]\n"]
]
,["group_config",null,null,null,null,[null,"[null,null,null,null,1,null,null,1]\n"]
]
,["image_group",null,null,null,null,[null,"[[[0,\"mdba4buxuK9BKM:\",[\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRR2V_IL-Zh_LdrVzgBgvq6zcL68YSL01zNGsQJxXTo2cpXaqVz6A\",256,197]\n,[\"https://www.30grad.shop/item/images/11296/3000x3000/azet-kmngang-shirt-fastlife.jpg\",3000,2315]\n,null,0,{\"2001\":[]\n,\"2003\":[null,\"RXXHApKYqqq7RM\",\"https://www.30grad.shop/hersteller/kmn-gang/\",\"KMN Gang | 30° Shop\",\"KMN Gang Azet T-Shirt Fast Life\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\"30° Merchandise Shop\"]\n}]\n]\n]\n"]
]
]
]
,["t-cuCqGEujB5w","iP3_T8N4D_s8","r-iP3_T8N4D_s8",[["enable_close_for_background",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,1]
]
,["initial_open",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,0]
]
,["remain_in_lightbox_container",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]
]
,["ux",null,null,null,null,[null,"[{\"220802553\":1}]\n"]
]
,["gsa",null,null,null,null,[null,"[{\"46740956\":0,\"244399487\":0}]\n"]
]
]
]
,["t-RHI35lUscno","igbzzOoE9k74","r-igbzzOoE9k74"]
,["t-3mFqq0A9uuY","iymxTruthWUk","r-iymxTruthWUk",[["hide_label_on_focus",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]
]
]
]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","iJcTl2Z4mNb0","r-iJcTl2Z4mNb0"]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","iLi8ChEUFkT8","r-iLi8ChEUFkT8"]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","iM4MogigWfMk","r-iM4MogigWfMk"]
]
]
```

Comment: javascriptserializer

Comment: Looks like it's JSON; that might help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: i tried to parse it but didn't success with JSON need some help

Comment: Seems like you have to prepare it before to be able to deserialize it, removing some escape characters. Would be helpful if you share here what have you tried so far, something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/ could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The given string is a json array (not a json object)
You can use Newtonsoft.json (add the NuGet package to your solution) to parse it into a JArray and do whatever you want with it.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s = "[\"root\",[[\"t-a2hICACK35I\",\"isYktsZwEVMQ\",\"r-isYktsZwEVMQ\",[[\"global_config\",null,null,null,null,[null,\"[\\\"AOvVaw0H3zstE2R8Hh96uT8kZylb\\\\u0026ust\\\\u003d1511890102832262\\\",null,0,null,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,null,1,1,1,1,0,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,0,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,0,0,null,null,1,null,400,null,null,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,0,0,\\\"NONE\\\",null,4,\\\"Related image\\\",7,0,\\\"%1$d\\\\u0026nbsp;\\\\u0026#215;\\\\u0026nbsp;%2$d\\\",0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,\\\"#222\\\",0,1,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,0]\\n\"]\r\n]\r\n,[\"group_config\",null,null,null,null,[null,\"[null,null,null,null,1,null,null,1]\\n\"]\r\n]\r\n,[\"image_group\",null,null,null,null,[null,\"[[[0,\\\"mdba4buxuK9BKM:\\\",[\\\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRR2V_IL-Zh_LdrVzgBgvq6zcL68YSL01zNGsQJxXTo2cpXaqVz6A\\\",256,197]\\n,[\\\"https://www.30grad.shop/item/images/11296/3000x3000/azet-kmngang-shirt-fastlife.jpg\\\",3000,2315]\\n,null,0,{\\\"2001\\\":[]\\n,\\\"2003\\\":[null,\\\"RXXHApKYqqq7RM\\\",\\\"https://www.30grad.shop/hersteller/kmn-gang/\\\",\\\"KMN Gang | 30° Shop\\\",\\\"KMN Gang Azet T-Shirt Fast Life\\\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\\\"30° Merchandise Shop\\\"]\\n}]\\n]\\n]\\n\"]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n,[\"t-cuCqGEujB5w\",\"iP3_T8N4D_s8\",\"r-iP3_T8N4D_s8\",[[\"enable_close_for_background\",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,1]\r\n]\r\n,[\"initial_open\",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,0]\r\n]\r\n,[\"remain_in_lightbox_container\",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]\r\n]\r\n,[\"ux\",null,null,null,null,[null,\"[{\\\"220802553\\\":1}]\\n\"]\r\n]\r\n,[\"gsa\",null,null,null,null,[null,\"[{\\\"46740956\\\":0,\\\"244399487\\\":0}]\\n\"]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n,[\"t-RHI35lUscno\",\"igbzzOoE9k74\",\"r-igbzzOoE9k74\"]\r\n,[\"t-3mFqq0A9uuY\",\"iymxTruthWUk\",\"r-iymxTruthWUk\",[[\"hide_label_on_focus\",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n]\r\n,[\"t-mqWFpp0vPaI\",\"iJcTl2Z4mNb0\",\"r-iJcTl2Z4mNb0\"]\r\n,[\"t-mqWFpp0vPaI\",\"iLi8ChEUFkT8\",\"r-iLi8ChEUFkT8\"]\r\n,[\"t-mqWFpp0vPaI\",\"iM4MogigWfMk\",\"r-iM4MogigWfMk\"]\r\n]\r\n]";
            var jArray = JArray.Parse(s);
            Console.WriteLine(jArray.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```